# How do i get looping

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, laravel-4

I want to make a loop like clockwork and this is the loop code I created

```
<?php  for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) ?>
```

After that I want to display the result of a iteration into the list by using Forms & HTML laravel 4.2

```
<?php echo Form::select('value['.$data['sale_payment_deadline']->id.']', [$i => "$i Hour"], $data['sale_payment_deadline']->value, array('class'=>'form-control','autocomplete'=>'off'));?>
```

But unfortunately it does not get all the looping I've made before, should i get the loop 1-24, but what happens is i only get 25
how to handle it? thanks for the help replied

Comment: When you say "it does not get all the looping.." what do you mean?

Comment: should i get the loop 1-24, but what happens is i only get 25 @GeorgeK

Comment: Is that second code inside your `for` loop? Because I don't see any brackets or a `endfor` there.

Comment: Can you share the **full** code you are using and not only some excerpts here and there?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$hours = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    array_push($hours, $i + " Hour");
}    

echo Form::select(
    'value['.$data['sale_payment_deadline']->id.']', 
    [$i => "$i Hour"], 
    $data['sale_payment_deadline']->value, 
    array('class'=>'form-control','autocomplete'=>'off')
);
?>
```

**Edit:**

After looking at the Laravel documentation you need to pass an array into the Form creation, which means you have to construct it before-hand.

Example: {{ Form::select('age', ['Under 18', '19 to 30', 'Over 30']) }}

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field

You might have to put the rest of the data into an array and iterate through it when you create the dropdown box.

Comment: the code is a bit right but unfortunately `Form :: select` keeps repeating, it should be repeated is an `option` in it

Comment: Just realised I used "x" instead of "i" in the for loop, I've changed it now, try again and let me know if it works.

Comment: So what happens to your form? What do you mean by "is repeated"?

Comment: like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VCzKGWaAxUO_K8cTdb8vAzW3v2YyXKt5/view?usp=sharing @GeorgeK

Comment: If you see the documentation for dropdown boxes you need to add an array into the Form::select, which means you have to construct it before-hand. http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field

Comment: You're welcome @AgusSuparman :) If you've sorted the problem out don't forget to close the question.

Comment: @AgusSuparman If you've found a solution by now feel free to close the question

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    echo Form::select('value['.$data['sale_payment_deadline']->id.']', 
       [$i => "$i Hour"],
       $data['sale_payment_deadline']->value,
       array('class'=>'form-control','autocomplete'=>'off')
    );
}

?>
```

Comment: the code is a bit right but unfortunately `Form :: select` keeps repeating, it should be repeated is an `option` in it

Comment: like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VCzKGWaAxUO_K8cTdb8vAzW3v2YyXKt5/view?usp=sharing @dg